# Provide Auth Header to Codegen CLI

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

Our Swagger URL requires an auth token for access.  In POSTman, it's a header named `Authorization` with a value of `Bearer <some token>`

I am trying to use the swagger codegen CLI to generate some clients https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#generators.  However, I have been unsuccessful in attempting to add the `-a` auth header appropriately.  I've tried several variations of the below:

(1)
`java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar generate -i <our swagger URL> -a Bearer,token`

(2) `java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar generate -i <our swagger URL> -a Authorization:Bearer,token`

(3) `java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar generate -i <our swagger URL> -a Bearer%20token`

Any idea how to properly format this `-a` flag with a Bearer token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
-a "HEADER_NAME: HEADER_VALUE"
```

In your example:

```
-a "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN"
```

Comment: Thank you!  Banging my head for 30 min and you solve it in 30 seconds :)  Will accept once enough time has passed